# entity is nil in my view controller but not app delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I want to use CoreData in a single view application (without a table view controller) so I took the core data code from a master/detail application and put it in the `AppDelegate` of my single view app, also importing core data etc. In the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in app delegate, I was able to get core data to work, inserting and retrieving data etc. However, when I try to do a fetch request in the main view controller, I'm getting this error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Dumbquiz''
```

In this view controller, I imported the CoreData framework, created a property for the managed object context in the header file like this

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext;
```

and then synthesized it

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext;
```

In view did load, this was my code where I try to retrieve the same data that I successfully fetched in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Dumbquiz" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;
    self.quizData = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    NSLog(@"quizdata %@", self.quizData);
```

Can you explain why I would be getting this error

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Dumbquiz''
```

in the view controller if I was able to fetch data in app delegate file?

code in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    Quoraquiz *failedBankInfo = [NSEntityDescription
                                       insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Dumbquiz"
                                       inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [failedBankInfo setValue:@"do you like big cupcakes" forKey:@"question"];
    [failedBankInfo setValue:@"yes" forKey:@"answer1"];
    [failedBankInfo setValue:@"no" forKey:@"answer2"];
    [failedBankInfo setValue:@"maybe" forKey:@"answer3"];
    [failedBankInfo setValue:@"maybe" forKey:@"correctAnswer"];
    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Dumbquiz" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    for (Quoraquiz *info in fetchedObjects) {
        NSLog(@"question: %@", [info valueForKey:@"question"]);

    }
```

Comment: Do you get the `moc` from your app delegate? Like this: `((myAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).managedObjectContext`? If so, try to breakpoint and make sure its not `nil`....

Comment: @AvielGross no I didn't, what method should I put that code in? I didn't see it in the master/detail application that I copied the other coredata code from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSManagedObjectContext` holds the context of certain state with the store (i.e. your core data information) plus all the changes. Every time you call `save:` to the `moc` ("Managed-Object-context) you save all the changes that are on the context to the core data (Basically your SQLite). When you call `reset:` you delete all the changes - leaving only a clean `moc` without any changes.
You need to have the same `moc` at all times, and with that `moc` handle all you Core Data calls.

To get the `moc` object from you app delegate:

```
((myAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).managedObjectContext;
```

Or to be on the safe side:

```
id delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = id.managedObjectContext;
}
```

If you need to set you app delegate, add this long code to you `.m` of the `appDelegate`:

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

#pragma mark - Core Data stack
- (void)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            Log(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
}

// Returns the managed object context for the application.
// If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

// Returns the managed object model for the application.
// If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"myDataModel" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

// Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
// If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"myDataModel.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

         Typical reasons for an error here include:
         * The persistent store is not accessible;
         * The schema for the persistent store is incompatible with current managed object model.
         Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.


         If the persistent store is not accessible, there is typically something wrong with the file path. Often, a file URL is pointing into the application's resources directory instead of a writeable directory.

         If you encounter schema incompatibility errors during development, you can reduce their frequency by:
         * Simply deleting the existing store:
         [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil]

         * Performing automatic lightweight migration by passing the following dictionary as the options parameter:
         @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES}

         Lightweight migration will only work for a limited set of schema changes; consult "Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide" for details.

         */
        Log(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

This is basically a code that apple wrote, and is pretty much copy/paste in most cases.
Just switch `myDataModel` with the name of your `xcdatamodeld` file.
Than in your `.h` add these:

```
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

Now every time you need a `moc` - get the one from your app delegate. You are also welcomed to save your `moc` using the method in the app delegate...

Comment: obviously you guys got the code working but two thoughts: 1) when you set up a delegate, it is good practice to create a protocol and declare it as id<MyDelegateProtocol> so there's a "contract" between entities and the IDE and compiler can help you, and 2) the fact that you are having to copy the managedObjectContext should be a hint that you've factored your code strangely and it invites problems. Seems far better to set up an interface where all the core-data work is on one side or the other, e.g. view controller just asks delegate for some data and gets an array back.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this code to my viewController fixed the problem

```
  id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  self.managedObjectContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];
```

Comment: I was assuming the worst in my answer... any way - for your solution you might want to add some precaution - using `id` like that might cause some dangerous situations, or for the least, bad habits... (:

Comment: @AvielGross actually my code was the same as your answer but it didn't work until I added the code in my answer, which I got from your comment. If you add that code from the comment to yours, I'll accept it